# Eloquent scope relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using `Laravel 5.4`

#### Code

```
 $usersWithFacebookNotifications = User::has('validSocialAccountForFacebookNotifications')
        ->has('activeFacebookNotifications')
        ->with('preferences')->with('socialAccount')
        ->get();
```

#### User model

```
public function activeFacebookNotifications () {
        return $this->notificationsChannels()
            ->where('active', 1)
            ->where('name', 'facebook_messenger');
    }


    public function validSocialAccountForFacebookNotifications () {
            return $this->socialAccount()
                ->where('provider', 'facebook')
                ->whereNotNull('page_scoped_id');
    }
```

#### Questions

Is it possible to create a scope relation in the `Users` model so I could call something like
`$users = User::has('allNeeded')->get();`

where `allNeeded` would be 
`activeFacebookNotifications + validSocialAccountForFacebookNotifications`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but a little bit different:

```
$users = User::allNeeded()->get();
```

And in your User model you add:

```
public function scopeAllNeeded($query)
{
    return $query
        ->has('validSocialAccountForFacebookNotifications')
        ->has('activeFacebookNotifications');
}
```